# Centring bar labels in bar plots in r

Tags: r, plot

How can I centre the labels on the x-axis to match up with the bars? Also, how can I position the x axis label further down so it it is not obscured by the x-axis labels? Thanks!

```
par(mar= c(15,4,4,2) + 0.1)
barplot(58:1,xaxt="n",xlab="",ylab="Frequency", col=gray(5:0/5))
axis(1, labels=FALSE)
text(1:58, par("usr")[3] - 0.25, srt = 90, adj = 1,
labels = rep("Long Species Name",58), xpd = TRUE)
mtext(1, text = "Species", line=6)
```

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check out the return value of `barplot()` (by reading `?barplot`). There we find that the mid points of the bars are returned by the function as a vector. Hence it is a simple matter of assigning the returned object (here to object `bar`) and then use that in a call to `axis()` to locate the tick marks.

In the `axis()` call, note that we specify both the `labels` argument **and** the `at` argument, with `at` being set to the bar mid points as stored in `bar`. `las = 2` is used to rotate the labels relative to the axis, and `cex.axis = 0.6` is used to reduce the label size.

The second part of your question is handled by `title()` and the `line` argument. First note that when you set the `mar` parameter you are setting the margin size in "lines", hence the margin on side 1 (bottom) is 15 lines. The `line` argument in `title()` specifies which of the margin lines you want to draw the axis label.

Putting this altogether with a modified example we have:

```
op <- par(mar= c(15,4,4,2) + 0.1)
bar <- barplot(58:1, xaxt="n", xlab="", ylab="Frequency", col=gray(5:0/5))
axis(1, labels = paste("Long Species Name", 1:58), at = bar,
     las = 2, cex.axis = 0.6)
title(xlab = "Species", line=11)
par(op)
```

Which produces:

[image: barplot produced using example code]

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation it was very clear. Thanks again!